# Suppose $X \sim \mathrm{Exp}(\lambda)$ and $Y = \ln(X)$. Find the probability density function of $Y$ .

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Suppose $X \sim \mathrm{Exp}(\lambda)$ and $Y = \ln(X)$. Find the probability density function of $Y$ .

I'm to a point on this problem where I don't know what to do from here, so any direction would be appreciated.

$P(Y \leq y)$

$P(\ln(X) \leq y)$

$P(X \leq e^y)$

I feel like I need to use the $X \sim \mathrm{Exp}(\lambda)$ now, but I'm not sure what to do.

Comment: Do you know any useful relationships between the pdf and the cdf?

Comment: See [math notation guide](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct till your last step. Note that the cumulative distribution function for X is such that:

$$P(X\leq x)=1-e^{-\lambda x}$$

---

So then what is $P(X\leq e^y)$ ?

$$P(X\leq e^y)=1-e^{-\lambda e^y}$$

Now , to obtain the pdf. You have to differentiate the C.D.F with respect to y.

Comment: So then I get λe^(y−λe^y), correct?

Comment: @user181928 Yes that's correct :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to integrate the pdf of $X$ to get the cdf. Assuming standard bounds, this is $1-e^{-\lambda x}$. Now substitute in $e^y$ for $x$ and you will get $1-e^{-e^{-y}}$